# Can we Encrypt and Download the application.properties File in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I got a requirement in Spring boot. I a nearly beginner so kindly ignore my mistake.

Main requirement is I have to encrypt all application.properties data so even someone get access, not be able to read. I don't know whether it is possible or not, So let me know that also.

Why want to do this - I Application.properties hold lots of credentials for DB and Data for other service and some how any hackers get's the credentials then he/she will get other data too of DB and API keys. So doing it for security purpose. It is some finance project.

Requirement: I have Encrypted application.properties file present on S3 Bucket and have to download from there and decrypt the file at the starting of project and the project will load the data from that application.properties file.

I broke down the problem in download and Encryption/Decryption:

1. So I know how to download file in Maven from URL in specific folder. - Done
2. How to Decrypt application.properties file and use it to load Credential. - Answer Looking for!

I got the ways by using Jasypt Library in Spring boot but that encrypt the value only.

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=pass
encrypted.property=ENC(S3oSEyuNwaFBrwfoaNhqvauLAui9F+L9)
```

And in Any Java file I get the value:

```
@Value("${encrypted.property}")
private String property;
```

But that is not hiding any data as If i get the Jasypt then i can decrypt data on Online websites also. And it is also not hiding the keys.

So didn't find it working according to my requirement. So kindly help me in this problem.

Comment: Ignoring wether or not it is possible it is useless anyway. If the client downloads the file and decrypts it then *I* can download the file and decrypt it. What is the point of all that other than adding complexity to your application?

Comment: @luk2302 We want to encrypt all the data present in application.properties as it will having DB credential and other auth keys. So thats why, If a hacker hacks our server he will able to access other data too. That's why we want to encrypt the data.

Comment: Does only the client have the key to decrypt the properties file and does every client have a different key for a different application.properties? Does every client have a different database he wants to access? If every client access the same db they need the same application.properties which means they all need to be able to decrypt the data which means the secret to decrypting the data is in the jar which means that if I get the jar I get the secret which means I can decrypt the application.properties file. What ***attack vector*** are you trying to protect against?

Comment: If you're using AWS anyway, you may want to look into [Amazon's key management](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/).

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for the reply. I am having talk with the team regarding this.

Comment: @AvinashVerma may be this is what you are looking for? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_encryption_and_decryption